# In arangodb how to save decimal with trailing zeroes in order to keep the precision of the value

Tags: decimal, precision, arangodb

So if the user inputs 12.00000 I need to save the trailing zeroes 5 in this example.

I am evaluating arangodb. But there is no clear information about this.

I would use BigDecimal in Java to handle the numbers or any other way that is ok by arango.

Answer (score 0):

Arango uses the same types as Javascript. You are essentially storing JSON data - which doesn't allow you to specify types.

So there are no decimal based numerical types. You would need to store the value as a string if you want to keep the decimals exactly, without conversion to floats.